# When vs while : I sprained my ankle ____ I was playing basketball

Tags: word-choice

> I sprained my ankle ____ I was playing basketball.

I went through an [earlier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141357/how-to-use-when-vs-while-on-the-following-occasions) post of *when vs while* on SE. The difference in meaning of those sentences is pretty clear but what difference does using the two words makes in the above sentence? Which one is more appropriate?
What I think is more appropriate is *while* because *play**ing*** tells that the action was going on when his angle was sprained. Am I correct?

Comment: Whoever wrote this question (I'm presuming it comes from a textbook or practice exam) is wanting you to think about the subtle difference between these two words. That's all well and good, but most native speakers could hear either word in the blank, and the sentence will sound just fine either way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [As, when or while?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69514/as-when-or-while)

Answer (score -1):

In conversational English, the difference is practically meaningless.

But, there is a possible *very subtle* difference.

**While** focuses on the fact your were actively playing basketball when you sprained your ankle.

**When** suggests that playing basketball was the cause of the sprain as opposed to other activities you engaged in.